# SQL Server - Migration script testing - Refresh table definition manually without dropping it

Tags: sql-server, migration, alter-table

How can a table definition be manually refreshed without also manually crafting a bunch of `ALTER TABLE` statements, or dropping and recreating the table?

This is normally handled by the publish process (e.g. SSDT), but during testing of schema alterations and their migration scripts, I need to revert the table definitions, and the managed rebuild/publish process through Visual Studio (and getting specific versions from TFS) takes quite a long time.

For example, if I have this new version of the table after updating the schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyAssociativeTable]
(
    [SurrogateID]   INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[ForeignID1]   INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [MyOtherTable1]([ID])
    ,[Flag1]        BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyAssociativeTable_Flag1] DEFAULT(0)
    ,[ForeignID2]   INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [MyOtherTable2]([ID])
    ,[Flag2]        BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MyAssociativeTable_Flag2] DEFAULT(0)
    ,[DataColumn1]  REAL NULL CONSTRAINT [CK_MyAssociativeTable_Data1] CHECK(ISNULL([DataColumn1], 0) >= 0)
    ,[ExtraColumn1] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_MyAssociativeTable] PRIMARY KEY
    (
        [ForeignKey1]
        ,[ForeignKey2]
    )
    ,CONSTRAINT [CK_MyAssociativeTable_Case1] CHECK
    (
        [Flag1] = 0
        OR [Flag2] = 0
    )
)
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [AK_MyAssociativeTable_F1]
ON [dbo].[MyAssociativeTable]([ForeignID1])
WHERE [Flag1] = 1
```

and I want to revert it to the original version (removing `ExtraColumn1` is ok) so I can insert *invalid* rows to test migration scripting on

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyAssociativeTable]
(
    [SurrogateID]   INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,[ForeignID1]   INT
    ,[ForeignID2]   INT
    ,[Flag1]        BIT
    ,[Flag2]        BIT
    ,[DataColumn1]  REAL
    ,PRIMARY KEY([SurrogateID])
)
```

what are my options?

<sub>Note that columns are also being re-ordered. Handling this would be nice, but is unimportant.</sub>

Comment: I would use a Schema Compare for this. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: No, we have never used that tool before, but should?

Answer (score 0):

One approach that works (only if there are no foreign keys referring to the table) is to create a backup of the original table with its original data.

Before starting to test the migration:

1. Grab a copy of the old table definition to define a copy of it, with a unique name (e.g. append "_bak" to the table name) **and all named constraints** (using `sp_rename` on just the table name will not automatically update named constrains).
2. `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [bak] ON`
3. Write a simple `INSERT INTO [bak] (\every column\) SELECT \every column\ FROM [original]` (the column list *must* be specified, otherwise you will get error 8101 for not explicitly writing out the identity column (why?))
4. `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [bak] OFF`

<sub>Note 1: Make sure to **not** enable the advanced SSDT publish option "drop objects in target not in source" or this table will get dropped if you publish.</sub>

<sub>Note 2: *Computed columns* must not be included in the `\every column\` list.</sub>

Then each time you want to revert the table definition and populate it with the preexisting records:

1. `DROP TABLE [target]`
2. Copy the original table definition and run that `CREATE TABLE ...` code
3. `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [target] ON`
4. `INSERT INTO [target](\every column\) SELECT \every column\ FROM [bak]`
5. `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [target] OFF`

This is still far too manual of a process however (and breaks on foreign keys).